# Did Adria Richards tweet "Black people CANNOT be racist..."?

Tags: quotes, racism

Did Adria Richards (known for the ["donglegate"](http://arstechnica.com/staff/2013/03/donglegate-is-classic-overreaction-and-everyone-pays/) and [similar incidents](http://amandablumwords.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/3/)) ever tweet the following?

> Black people CANNOT be racist against White poeple. Racist is a
>   position of the opressor who has the power

The source of the claim is alleged screenshot:

[image]

[source: KnowYourMeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/donglegate-adria-richards/photos)

Comment: @Sancho I think you are missing the point. The person that made this comment in and of themselves is not a notable person. There must be a minimum bar for notability for which I don't feel hat this question really meets. That's likely a better [discussion for meta](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2322) though.

Comment: Chat room about this question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8807/adria-richards-question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes she did.

[Link to that Twitter-post](https://twitter.com/adriarichards/status/6039856858)

> [image: Screenshot of the quote, indicating it was posted "2:56PM 25 Nov 09"]

In case the tweet is removed here's the [Archive.org copy of it](https://web.archive.org/web/20131211160718/https://twitter.com/adriarichards/status/6039856858).

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why I didn't get any results using search on Twitter.

Comment: Possibly because it's from 2009?

Comment: @Oddthinking Well it felt a bit silly to post a screenshot of the twitter, when question used a screenshot as a claim... Picture need a date stamp then.

Comment: @Wertilq: good point, there is really no way of saying if the screenshot is third party or not. In HTML/JS it's possible to actually embed a tweet, but I don't think it's possible here.

Comment: @Wertliq: Yes, I agree. I felt a little silly adding it for that reason, but I felt it was important, because controversial tweets are often deleted. My compromise was (a) this screen-shot is better than the original because it includes the posting date, (b) in the edit log, I solemnly swear this is a true copy. I admit that is a borderline anecdote, but I hoped it would be sufficient to convince people if the original was deleted.